# OpenVPN all subnets the same, send a single client to tun0?

Tags: networking, openvpn, linux-networking

The two networks in question are listed here.. The wlan0 is on 10.0.0.23/24. tun0 (openvpn) is on 10.8.0.6 but is routing traffic to the network 10.0/16. So both wlan0, and perhaps tun0 could have traffic destined for 10.0.0.130, I want to explicitly route traffic to 10.0.0.130 to tun0. How do I set this up?

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:4e:36:c4:59:0c  
          inet addr:10.0.0.23  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e4e:36ff:fec4:590c/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2783796 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1239437 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3249807030 (3.2 GB)  TX bytes:237142115 (237.1 MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be as simple as adding a route statement in your OpenVPN configuration on the client.  Something like the below, if you only want to redirect the single address.

```
route 10.0.0.130 255.255.255.255
```

Comment: The problem is wlan0 is already on 10.0.0.0/24, and I want the traffic from that address to go to tun0.

Comment: That is why I used a **32bit** mask (255.255.255.255) in the route.  This route matches a a single address.

Comment: BTW, I am not be understanding a your network.  A diagram would be helpful. As would the current routing table of the client with the VPN active.